# Do I need a manager when creating and saving objects in Django?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, model

I'm using Django with Python 3.7 and PyCharm.  I'm following this tutorial for learning how to create model and save them into the database -- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#creating-objects .  The tutorial refers to manager for retrieving objects, but not for setting them, so I'm confused as to why I get the below error

```
Article.objects.create_article(main page, '/path', 'url', 10, 22)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Manager' object has no attribute 'create_article'
```

when I'm trying to create and save an object.  Below is how I define my object in my models.py file ...

```
class Article(models.Model):
    mainpage = models.ForeignKey(MainPage, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    path = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    url = models.TextField
    time = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    comments = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.path

    @classmethod
    def create(cls, mainpage, path, url, votes, comments):
        article = cls(mainpage=mainpage,path=path,url=url,votes=votes,comments=comments)
        return article
```

I'm sure I'm missing something really obvious, but I don't know what it is.

**Edit:** Many have suggested using the "Article.objects.create" method but below is the output from the console ...

```
Article.objects.create(mainpage=mainpage, path='/path', url='url', votes=10, comments=22)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/mainarticles_project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/mainarticles_project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 411, in create
    obj = self.model(**kwargs)
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/mainarticles_project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 485, in __init__
    raise TypeError("'%s' is an invalid keyword argument for this function" % kwarg)
TypeError: 'url' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

Comment: Have you tried `Article.create(...)` ? You defined the method `.create()` on the class `Article`, not on the manager. Or you could also define the method on the manager, which would be more in line with Djangos convention.

Comment: the method name is create and the function you calling is create_article. anyway I'm  not sure why you want to create objects like this. the tutorial you've linked is very clear and simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create an article in database use manager's create method (params should be named, not positioned, as in your example)

```
Article.objects.create(mainpage=mainpage, path=path, url=url, 
                       votes=votes, comments=comments)
```

or you can initialise class instance and then save it. Here params could be positioned or named, no matter.

```
article = Article(mainpage, path, url, votes, comments)
article.save()
```

Your method `def create(cls, mainpage, path, url, votes, comments):` makes no sense, because it duplicates call (`__call__` method) of a class, like in my second example. If you want to add some extra logic to object creation, you should define custom `Manager` class and add method there and then link your model's objects property to you custom manager class like `objects = CustomManager()`

Comment: I tried your first example, "Article.objects.create", but this gave me the error, "TypeError: 'url' is an invalid keyword argument for this function".  Does that make any sense, because it doesn't to me?

Comment: `url = models.TextField` there's a typo here in your model code. You should call field `url = models.TextField()`, then django will do its magic linking field with model

Comment: Doh!  Didn't notice that.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

When you define a Model Class, Django jumps into the fray and adds a default [Manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/managers/) to your model under the "objects" property.  You can customize the Model *and* the Manager for different purposes.

Generally methods on your Model should deal with a single instance, or conceptually a row in your database.  `Model.save()`, `Model.delete()` all act on a single instance or row.

Methods on your manager should usually work with your table as a whole, such as `filter()`, `get()`, `aggregate()`, because these functions perform operations against your table.  You also have the `create()` method on your manager because it adds a row to your table.  Further, you can define custom Manager's and assign them to different properties on your model. For example:

```
class EngineerManager(Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(employee_type="engineer")

class ManagerManager(Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(employee_type="manager")

class Employee(Model):
    employee_type = models.CharField()

    engineers = EngineerManager()
    managers = ManagerManager()
    objects = Manager()  # This is always added to your models to list all objects

Employee.engineers.filter()  # Will only return engineering employees
Employee.objects.filter()  # Will return ALL employees
```

Now to your problem, `Article.objects.create_article(...)` does not seem to exist, you should probably use `Article.objects.create(...)` because the default Manager does have a `create()` method.

Using `Article.objects.create(...)` will persist a new Article to the database and return it.  Otherwise, you could technically use your `Article.create(...)` method to create an in-memory instance of Article, however it has not been saved to the database so keep in mind you will have to call `save()` on the instance before it's persisted to your database.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/managers/